# Splitting array on new line

Tags: java

I am submitting the following input through stdin:

4 2

30 one

30 two

15 three

25 four

My code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String submittedString;
        System.out.flush();
        submittedString = stdin.readLine();

        zipfpuzzle mySolver = new zipfpuzzle();
        mySolver.getTopSongs(submittedString);

    }
```

Which calls:

```
//Bringing it all together
    public String getTopSongs(String myString) {

        setUp(myString);
        calculateQuality();
        qualitySort();
        return titleSort();

    }
```

Which calls

```
public void setUp(String myString) {

    String tempString = myString;

    //Creating array where each element is a line
    String[] lineExplode = tempString.split("\\n+");

    //Setting up numSongsAlbum and songsToSelect
    String[] firstLine = lineExplode[0].split(" ");
    numSongsAlbum = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[0]);
    songsToSelect = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[1]);

    System.out.println(lineExplode.length);
//etc
}
```

However, for some reason lineExplode.length returns value 1... Any suggestions?

Kind Regards,
Dario

Comment: It would be much better to understand your problem if you show your complete code..

Comment: @DarioPanada You reading only one line here.

Comment: Did you try: `str.split(Pattern.quote(System.getProperty("line.separator")) + '+')` as I suggested in my answer?

Comment: But how is that happening?

Comment: Ah you read just one line (till `\n`) in this line: `submittedString = stdin.readLine();` and I don't see any loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] lineExplode = tempString.split("\\n+");
```

The argument to String#split is a String that contains a regular expression

Comment: I have changed it to String[] lineExplode = tempString.split("\\n"); but am still getting the same result

Comment: @DarioPanada Try using String[] lineExplode = tempString.split("\\n+");

Comment: Done that too :) let me know

Answer (score 1):

Your `String#split` regex will work file on Strings with newline characters.

```
String[] lineExplode = tempString.split("\n");
```

The problem is that your `tempString` has none of these characters, hence the size of the array is `1`.

Why not just put the readLine in a loop and add the Strings to an ArrayList

```
String submittedString;
while (!(submittedString= stdin.readLine()).equals("")) {
   myArrayList.add(submittedString);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how however, the input I'm providing is on multiple lines

Comment: Yes but lines read using `BufferedReader#readLine` do not include newline characters

Comment: Oh, alright, then this make sense... What can I use instead? For what I need it input needs to be provided via Stdin

Comment: Why not just put the `readLine` in a loop and add the Strings to an `ArrayList`? Then you won't need to split them

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use this split this way:

```
String[] lineExplode = 
       tempString.split(Pattern.quote(System.getProperty("line.separator")) + '+');
```

To keep this split on new line **platform independent**.

**UPDATE:** After looking at your posted code it is clear that OP is reading just one line (till \n) in this line:

```
 submittedString = stdin.readLine();
```

and there is no loop to read further lines from input.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file is using UNIX-style line endings (\n)? For a cross-platform split, use:

```
String[] lineExplode = tempString.split("[\\n\\r]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "\\n" character to separate by new line but check that not all OS use the same separators ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline )

To solve this is very useful the system property **line.separator** that contains the current separator charater(s) for the current OS that is running the application.

You should use:

```
String[] lineExplode = tempString.split("\\\\n");
```

using \n as separator

Or:

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String[] lineExplode = tempString.split(lineSeparator);
```

Using the current OS separator

Or:

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String[] lineExplode = tempString.split(lineSeparator + "+");
```

Using the current OS separator and requiring one item